# How to iterate through outputs of different functions?

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I am trying to create a binomial expansion calculator (one of my first coding projects so my code might be a bit iffy) and I have come up with functions which calculate each of the terms a, b and x (in (a + bx)^n) separately.

I am not sure how to multiply an output from ExpandA with an output from ExpandB, while iterating through the list to print out each term in the expansion.

Any tips and hints would be highly appreciated!

## Binomial Expansion Calculator

```
def expansion():
    def ExpandA(): # Calculates a^n, a^(n-1), a^(n-2)) ... a^0
        for i in range (entry_n,-1,-1): #Start,end,step
        #end at entry_n.get()-1 so computer can calculate a^0    
           print(entry_a**i)         
            
    def ExpandB(): # Calculates b^0, b^1, b^2 ... b^n
        for i in range(0,(int(entry_n)+1),1):
            print(entry_b**i)
            
    def XValues():# Prints x^0, x^1, x^2 ... x^n
        for i in range(0,int(entry_n+1),1):
            print("X^",i)
    ExpandA()
    ExpandB()
    XValues()
    

print("Welcome to the Binomial Expansion Calculator!")
print("Please enter your inputs in the form (a + bx ^n).")

entry_a = int(input("Please enter your 'a' value."))
entry_b = int(input("Please add your 'b' value."))
entry_n = int(input("Please enter your 'n' value."))

expansion()
```

Comment: It's really helpful here to post runnable code examples. You care making us guess what all these `entry_` variables are and why `IntN` is global but used as a loop variable. Can you make a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I'm new to this format. I used tkinter which is why I didn't want to post my full piece of code. I have rewritten it so it only uses Python. I hope this is more helpful.

Comment: Any other tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well from the looks of things, you're just printing numbers from a range in all 3 functions. You would want to *return* or *yield* the values instead of printing them.

```
def expandA(): # Calculates a^n, a^(n-1), a^(n-2)) ... a^0
    for i in range (entry_n,-1,-1): #Start,end,step
       yield entry_a**i         

def expandB(): # Calculates b^0, b^1, b^2 ... b^n
    for i in range(0,(int(entry_n)+1),1):
        yield entry_b**i

def xvalues():# Prints x^0, x^1, x^2 ... x^n
    for i in range(0,int(entry_n+1),1):
        yield "X^",i

# the following will return generator objects
as = expandA()
bs = expandB()
xs = xvalues()

# so you can access the values like this:
for a, b, x in zip(as, bs, xs):
    print("{} + {}{}{}".format(a, b, x[0], x[1]))
```

Note that the xvalues function yields tuples instead of single values

Comment: You could simplify the code for xvalues to return just the iterator, and then put "X^" in the format string, since it is a constant value in this use case. This might also be a case for using a class object to represent the individual pieces, but it wouldn't change the code provided by much. The only other criticism I'd have for an otherwise exemplary answer is the use of "as" for a variable name, since it is a reserved keyword. Great solution to the problem, though, without changing much of the original.